# Variable Defined in Else Is Ignored in If

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to build divs based on unique values. So for each line, the script checks the team name against $tempTeam. If they're equal, the line gets added to the table in the existing div. If they're not equal, a new div and table is created, and the line is added there.

However, the if part isn't recognizing when $tempTeam is equal to the team so it never runs, even though the else part is properly setting $tempTeam. So I'm wondering why the variable is working for the else part of the code, but not the if part.

Here's the full code, although the trouble begins when I first define $tempTeam. Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
$csv = file_get_contents('schedules.csv');

$csv_array = explode("\n", $csv);
unset($csv_array[count($csv_array) - 1]);
$headers = explode(",", $csv_array[0]);

// iterate through all lines of CSV, skipping first header line
for($i=1;$i<count($csv_array);$i++) {

  $line = explode(",", $csv_array[$i]);

  // iterate through all headers and assign corresponding line value
  foreach ($headers as $index => $header){
    $parsed_array[$i][$header] = $line[$index];
  }

}

// create divs and tables
$tempTeam = '';
foreach ($parsed_array as $i => $match) {

    if ($tempTeam == $match['Team']) {
        echo "
            <tr><td>$match[Date]</td><td>$match[Result]</td><td>$match[Location]</td><td>$match[Opponent]</td></tr>
        ";
    }

  else if ($tempTeam == '') {
        $tempTeam = $match['Team'];
    echo "
            <div class=\"schedule\" data-container=\"$match[League]\">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan=\"4\">$match[Team]</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th><th>Result</th><th>Location</th><th>Opponent</th>
            </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>$match[Date]</td><td>$match[Result]</td><td>$match[Location]</td><td>$match[Opponent]</td></tr>
        ";
    }

      else {
        $tempTeam = $match['Team'];
    echo "
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class=\"schedule\" data-container=\"$match[League]\">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan=\"4\">$match[Team]</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th><th>Result</th><th>Location</th><th>Opponent</th>
            </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>$match[Date]</td><td>$match[Result]</td><td>$match[Location]</td><td>$match[Opponent]</td></tr>
        ";
    }
}
echo "
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
";          
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, look at the first line of the `else` clause:

```
$tempTeam == $match['Team'];
```

I'm *pretty* certain that's not what you wanted to do, it seems to me that *assignment* would probably be a better choice than comparison.

What you're doing is no different to:

```
$a = 1;
$a == $a + 1;
print ($a);
```

which will still output `1` rather than `2`. If you want do do assignment, it should have just the *one* `=` character:

```
$tempTeam = $match['Team'];
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks a lot for catching it. It works exactly as it should now.